# Storing Multiple References in React Component vs Querying DOM by ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I'm building a form in react and would like to autofocus on the first invalid field after submission. To do this I need to access to a reference of the invalid field and call `.focus()` on it. My question is then is it better (more performant) to store multiple references in the constructor or just attach an ID to every field and query the DOM to grab the reference.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.props.entry;
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    this.field1 = React.createRef();
    this.field2 = React.createRef();
    this.field3 = React.createRef();
    this.field4 = React.createRef();
}
...

this.field3.focus();
```

vs.

```
document.getElementById(`form_${fieldId}`).focus();
```

Essentially, would it be unnecessary to to store a reference to every form input instead of querying the DOM by ID once?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap `<input>` in a component you can establish a single ref and delegate the functionality:

```
class TextInput extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.input = React.createRef();
  }

  focus = () => {
    this.input.current.focus()
  }

  render() {
    return(<input ref={this.input} />)
  }
}

// elsewhere...
const text_input = React.createElement(TextInput)
text_input.focus() #=> calls the `focus` method defined above
```

Comment: I mean this is essentially just pushing the createRef farther down the pipeline. You're still creating a reference for every input you'd need, just wrapping it in a PureComponent rather than leaving attached to the parent form. I guess what I'm asking is if creating a lot of references is more/less performant in comparison to querying the DOM by ID.

Comment: A ref is pretty lightweight in implementation terms—you can have a thousand refs and not notice. I assumed your goal was to DRY up your constructor. In any case, you ought to break out small components for this sort of thing anyways.